# Using a free "char const*" at static initialization time

Tags: c++, initialization-order

Initialization order of free objects is undefined in C++. But what about the following?

```
namespace foo {
    char const* str = "hey";
    struct A {
        A() { cout << str; }
    } obj;
}
```

Is this still undefined behavior, or is there a special provision for pointers initialized with string literals?

**Aside from that**: what if str was of type "char const[]"? And if it was a std::string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialisation order is defined - they are initialised in the order they appear in a compilation unit - see section 3.6.2 of the C++ Standard. The type of the things being initialised has no effect.

Comment: -1: This is wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750407/do-objects-of-built-in-types-have-special-static-initialisation-order-precedence

Answer (score 5):

Even if they would be located in different translation units, the initialisation order is still defined.

That is because `str` is initialized with a constant expression (`address constant expression`) and `str` has pod-type. It would still hold true if you had an array. But it would not be true anymore if you had a `std::string`. Those are dynamically initialized (because `std::string` is a non-POD).

Thus, if your `str` were a `std::string`, you would run into undefined behavior if `obj` is defined in a different translation unit, but that's the only case of the one you listed that would cause trouble.