# Do objects of built-in types have special static initialisation order precedence?

Tags: c++, static-initializer

I'd have expected the following code to yield a segmentation fault (or otherwise UB):

```
struct T {
   T();
};

T t;
char const* str = "Test string";

T::T() {
   std::cout << str; // zero-initialised, only!
}

int main() {}
```

That's because `t` is initialised before `str`. I'd expect `str` to hold the value `(char const*)0` due to zero-initialisation. My interpretation of `[C++11: 3.6.2/2]` supports this.

However, [the above snippet appears to output the string as expected](http://codepad.org/9E7urd66) (and I confirmed the behaviour by also printing the pointer's value).

Is there some rule of static initialisation that I'm missing here, that allows `str` to be value-initialised before `t` begins construction? Where is it in the standard?

---

<sup>This came up on [static variable resolution at build time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8749841/560648), where an answerer asserted that using `char const*` rather than `std::string` for a static global avoids the static initialisation order fiasco. I disagreed, but now I'm not so sure...</sup>

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/790687/34509 for a question that currently has an accepted but unfortunately wrong answer.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it; what's happening here is not so much about the built-in type, but about the constant initialiser:

> `[C++11: 3.6.2/2]:` Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.
>
> ***Constant initialization* is performed:**
>
> - if each *full-expression* (including implicit conversions) that appears in the initializer of a reference with static or thread storage duration is a constant expression (5.19) and the reference is bound to an lvalue designating an object with static storage duration or to a temporary (see 12.2);
> - if an object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constructor call, if the constructor is a `constexpr` constructor, if all constructor arguments are constant expressions (including conversions), and if, after function invocation substitution (7.1.5), every constructor call and full-expression in
>     the *mem-initializers* and in the *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members is a constant expression;
> - **if an object with static or thread storage duration is not initialized by a constructor call and if every *full-expression* that appears in its initializer is a constant expression.**
>
> **Together, *zero-initialization* and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization. Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place.** [..]

That final sentence would seem to override subsequent sequencing rules, making this ordering apply across Translation Units.

Comment: Your last conclusion is incorrect. Only dynamic initialization can be "unordered" or "ordered". These two terms do not apply to static initialization. Order is no issue at all there.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: OK, how about the preceding two sentences, which repeat pretty much the same rule but without the word "unordered"?

Comment: they say "Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place.". That's a hard requirement. There is no room for implementations to not follow that requirement.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Hmm... I suppose.. will revisit

Answer (score 6):

`str` is initialized by a constant expression and `const char *` is a POD type (C++03 terms, but C++11 it is analogous, but with different terms and way more allowed cases). Such an initialization is done in *static* initialization phase, and the *static* initialization phase has no issue of order. It happens before any *dynamic* initialization. `t` is initialized in the *dynamic* initialization phase.

Comment: Is this covered by the passage I cited? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @Light yes you cited the c++11 text.

Comment: I'm not convinced that "str is initialized by a constant expression". It takes a string literal's address, which is certainly not a constant expression. Therefore str should have dynamic initialization. However implementations are permitted (3.6.2/3) to initialize it statically.

Comment: @Timo: I'm sure a string literal is a constant expression. All literals ought to be (`5.19/2`). That the pointer value may change between builds and invocations is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in types aren't initialised at all, in the normal sense. Commonly, their initial contents are memory-mapped directly from a special region of the binary as part of loading it.

Comment: Turns out they are. That act is apparently known as "constant initialization".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Logically, yes. Physically, you'll find no code anywhere that says, "assign the address of this string-literal to `str`". That's what I meant by, "in the normal sense".

Comment: *nods* Thanks. Was looking for standard reasoning though, so logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
char const* str = "Test string";
```

is done by the compiler/linker, so it exists in its "initialized state" before the program even starts to run.